# Is there a way to download a .jar file with a httpurlconnection?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

The server is sending a jar file and i want to save it in a specific directory.
My HttpURLConnection is only reading the content of the file

```
public static String update(String url, String version) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        
    return readResponse(con.getInputStream());
}
```

```
private static String readResponse(InputStream in){
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((in)));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String output;
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(output);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: A JAR file isn't text and doesn't contain lines. You should be using an `InputSream`, not a `Reader`, and certainly not `readLine()` or `String`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are u parsing it as a string?
Maybe try (https://www.baeldung.com/java-download-file)

```
InputStream in = new URL(FILE_URL).openStream();
Files.copy(in, Paths.get(FILE_NAME), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: NB: This code will leak memory, it needs try-with-resources.